# Ionic 2 Can't handle menu in front a google maps element

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have made an Ionic V2 side menu application and integrated to it an GMaps element. But I can't handle the element which be in front of that map. The buttons of the side menu are disabled if they are in front of the map and it the same for the pop up of a ionic select element.

So my question is, where is my mistake ? Why I can't handle any element in front of the google map element ?

I can't handle the zone squared in red :

[image] [image]

My map html code :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Carte</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-row center>
    <ion-col width-25 center>
      <ion-label>Jours :</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25 center>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
        <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25 center>
      <ion-label>Horaires :</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25 center>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
        <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <div #map id="map" style="height:90%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

My map ts code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng, CameraPosition, GoogleMapsMarkerOptions, GoogleMapsMarker } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-gmap',
  templateUrl: 'gmap.html'
})
export class GMap {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
    let map = new GoogleMap(element);

    // listen to MAP_READY event
    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => console.log('Map is ready!'));
    // create LatLng object
    let ionic: GoogleMapsLatLng = new GoogleMapsLatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802);
    // create CameraPosition
    let position: CameraPosition = {
      target: ionic,
      zoom: 18,
      tilt: 30
    };
    // move the map's camera to position
    map.moveCamera(position);
    // create new marker
    let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
      position: ionic,
      title: 'Ionic'
    };

    map.addMarker(markerOptions).then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
      marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
// handle side menu issue...
let leftMenu = this.menuController.get('left');

if (leftMenu) {
  leftMenu.ionOpen.subscribe(() => {
    if (this.map) {
      this.map.setClickable(false);
    }
  });

  leftMenu.ionClose.subscribe(() => {
    if (this.map) {
      this.map.setClickable(true);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try on thursday

Comment: It's worked for the side menu but not for the pop up, I will try to subscribe the pop up to the map but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All the elements over the map that you want to be able to click must be inside the div that the map was linked.

So your code should look like:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Carte</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div #map id="map" style="height:90%;">
        <ion-row center>
            <ion-col width-25 center>
                <ion-label>Jours :</ion-label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-25 center>
                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
                    <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-25 center>
                <ion-label>Horaires :</ion-label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-25 center>
                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
                    <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```